# framework 7 onclick event bind not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html-framework-7, event-binding

I'm using [framework7.io](http://framework7.io). I'm using their framework events and functioning but the **onclick** event is not bind with their page event **pageInit**.

I'm try to access form Data and convert it to json using `formTOJSON` as shown below.

JS part

```
//on page in it if page load via ajax 
$$(document).on('pageInit', function() {

    /*========query form=======*/

    var queryForm = app.formToJSON('#query-form');
    $$('#query-submit').on('click', function () {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(queryForm));
    });

});
```

HTML part

```
<form id="query-form">
                    <div class="color-error" id="formErrorField" style="display: none;"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="item-content">
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                    <div class="item-input">
                                        <textarea name="question" placeholder="Type Here!"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br/>
                    <a href="#" class="button button-fill" id="query-submit">Submit</a>
                </form>
```

The same code is working for a different page load **(non-ajax).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually binding seems fine in your code.
Keep formToJSON code inside click event handle block try this:

```
$$(document).on('pageInit', function() {
    var queryForm = null;
    $$('#query-submit').on('click', function () {
     queryForm = app.formToJSON('#query-form');
       console.log(JSON.stringify(queryForm));
    });
});
```

Because when PageInit is happening your queryForm variable is empty according to your code.After filling the form you want to get value.So keep inside the click event handler.
Hope this helps.

Comment: There is one more issue. 'pageinit' called twice on loading of page.

Comment: Actually you are calling onPageInit on document so First It is calling when whole document is loading and second when it is actually loading in View. you can use this ~app.onPageInit('about', function (page) { // code here}); //about is your Data-Page attribute.